# Unable to save file content using SaveFileDialog

Tags: c#

I am not able to save content of a text file while using the save option in notepad in visual c#

The code I have used is:-

```
private void saveToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string s = richTextBox1.Text;

    if (saveFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        richTextBox1.SaveFile(saveFileDialog1.FileName,RichTextBoxStreamType.RichText);
    }           
}
```

Comment: What is the error you get?

Answer (score -1):

You need to use `RichTextBoxStreamType.PlainText`

Hence code should be -

```
private void saveToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string s = richTextBox1.Text;

    if (saveFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        richTextBox1.SaveFile(saveFileDialog1.FileName,RichTextBoxStreamType.PlainText);
    }           
}
```